# Rust logging library for event/data (not string) logging

Tags: logs, log-analysis, rust

I'm looking for a rust library that I can use to log *data*, as opposed to *log messages*. I know this sounds weird, so let me explain.

Let's say I have an app that connects to other 'things' over the network, and will receive different packets from them. I'd like to log whenever I receive a 'message', and what I'd normally do is something along the lines of
`log(Level::Info, "got message from {client}: {message}");`, or similar. If I end up getting messages from lots of different sources, it gets quite messy, because if either:

1. I have to duplicate this code in lots of places. This gets quite tricky, because I'll need to keep all these different locations in sync whenever something is changed (let's say I need to format the message differently to hide sensitive data).
2. I create a function `log_message(...)` and reuse this every time.

I was hoping to find some sort of library that would enable me to do something similar to (2), but slightly better; I would create a 'log event' struct, and completely avoid the need for string log messages:

```
struct MessageEvent{
    pub message: Message
}

impl LogEvent for MessageEvent{
    //...
}
```

and then be able to use it like so:

```
log(MessageEvent{message});
```

and whenever I decide to change how message events are handled, I only need to change the `impl LogEvent for MessageEvent`. Also, it would then allow me to easily 'look at' log events and do things like:

- Intercept certain events in a custom logger class that would hide 'sensitive' log events
- Test code by watching the log events

Note how these would be really nice to do because I'd only have to work with the event `struct`s themselves, and not with formatted `string` log events how you normally would. This would also mean that I can work directly with the events (let's say I serialise them as JSON and write them to a file), which is a plus as I just said.

I'd also like to point out that while libraries like `tracing` are very nice, they still require me to use `str` log messages, and I've found `tracing`'s formatting of message properties to be very poor in the past.

## Similar Posts

I did do a search before posting, and there are absolutely no posts remotely similar to this.
After searching for "rust log" (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=rust+log), these are the results:
[image: rust log search results]

As you can see, none of them answer my question.